# Is the interjection おう really a Chinese loanword?

Tags: etymology

In Samuel E. Martin's "A Reference Grammar of Japanese", in a section (Chapter 23, p. 1041) on putative etymologies for some Japanese interjections like さあ or まあ, he asserts:

> Although others [other interjections] seem like little more than grunts or shouts — aa, yaa, yoo — they may have originated as shortenings of more legitimate etyma; oo 'yea' is, after all, a Chinese loanword.

Really? If so, a loan from which Chinese word?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is true. If it was, it would probably be from 哦 (pronounced 'o') though, which is the chinese equivalent. I'm just not a believer that interjections are 1) words 2) are even loaned from other languages that often 3) aren't generally just coincidentally the same amongst all languages because that's the way people are. I'd try find another source for the claim that it's a loanword before I'd be willing to believe it.

Comment: Exactly, that's why it didn't pass muster for me. But he asserts it as if it were a well known fact, so I decided to put it to the community.

Comment: Does he give a source in the back of the book maybe? Otherwise maybe someone from JSE can hunt one down for an answer ; )

Comment: The book does have a bibliography but this particular claim  isn't resolved to a source.

Comment: The Chinese equivalent interjection would be 哦, without doubt. It's pinyin under this context is 'o', and it's used under the same usage as the Japanese おう as an interjection. Very few hanzi are read as 'o', and none of them except this one match the meaning of おう. In fact, this hanzi *perfectly* matches the usage of おう as an interjection (to mean "oh", or similar).

Comment: This character is definitely non-Joyo, despite being a common Chinese hanzi. But, the Japanese only has one listed on'yomi: が. Its kun'yomi are うたう, and よむ [http://kanji.quus.net/kakijyun/3561.htm] [http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%93%A6]. From this, it doesn't appear that Japan has ever seen its phonetic value as お, something not likely for a loanword. Without a historical work showing its pronunciation as お (or おう), this is a difficult claim to back up, and no current listed works show it as bearing this pronunciation in Japanese.

Comment: It's not conclusive enough for a full answer, but it's the best I can do without much more access to historical Japanese works. hopefully somebody on JSE can settle this more conclusively

Comment: A quick dictionary lookup gives this as a candidate `【嗚嗚】オオ　声をはりあげるさま。歌うとき、泣くときなどに用いる。「賢兄小姑哭嗚嗚=賢兄小姑哭して嗚嗚たり」〔李賀・箜篌引〕` 李賀 is apparently a Chinese author, but I can only find the Mandarin and Cantonese pronunciation wu1 for 嗚 -- perhaps an older pronuciation was different or `wu` sounds similar to お? Also, this still needs some sources that it was actually used in *Japan*, and I'm not sure how its meaning matches with `yea`...

Comment: @blutorange Interesting idea. 嗚's middle chinese pronunciation was in fact /?o/, so phonologically it makes sense. But, 嗚嗚 is used for crying sounds, and not so much similar in usage to おう, so the meaning doesn't match at all. The only compound with 嗚 in Japanese is 嗚咽{おえつ}, meaning to wimper. I just don't think the sound alone is a strong argument, especially when so much of Chinese is homophones...

Comment: I don't understand the edit.  日本国語大辞典 lists it under おお, though they say it's been variously written as おう・おお・あう・わう・をう, among others.

Comment: What about 唯唯?  It was written that way in the oldest cite in 日本国語大辞典.  Does that give us a clue?

Comment: 唯唯 is slightly old chinese word for replying obediently (along the lines of saying "yes yes" to whatever your elders say). Also, it's on'yomi are ゆい and い, none of them お (at least not anymore). The chinese is also "weiwei", and doesn't seem to ever have been 'o' in historical Chinese. 
The issue with that theory's on the Chinese end of things that it was never pronounced that way...

Comment: @sqrtbottle When I re-read the quoted passage, Martin does not make any claims about how it was pronounced in Chinese. As long as it is/was pronounced 'oo" in Japanese and its (kanji) spelling had been borrowed from Japanese, might that not count as what he describes?

Comment: @blutorange, Martin's text is somewhat cryptic, but the only way I can read this is that he's stating that the ~sound~ _oo_ as an affirmative interjection somehow came from Chinese.  The spelling seems immaterial here, not least because he doesn't provide any.  I'm'a be blunt and call "bullshit" on Martin's claim: 1) monosyllabic interjections are highly unlikely candidates for borrowing, and 2) he gives no detail as to where he thinks this purportedly originated in Chinese, and 3) none of the potential Chinese etyma fit in terms of both reading and meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Martin has 応 (old form 應) in mind. This was not uncommonly used to write *ō*, especially in Edo times. A famous haiku by Kyorai:

> 応々といへどたたくや雪の門
> ō ō to / iedo tataku ya / yuki no kado
> "All right, all right!" / I say, but the knocking doesn't stop / at the gate in the snow

However, I agree with the commenters that *ō* is unlikely to have been borrowed from Chinese at all -- not least because it appears in the Nihon Shoki as 越々, i.e. /wowo/ (which incidentally isn't easy to reconcile with any Chinese pronunciation of 応/應), and only got attached to 応/應 later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm astounded to see a series of the answers and comments to this question. Most of them are misguiding and confusing the O.P. They lack even a beginner's knowledge of Chinese language about how to read it and what it means.

None of “応、鳴、唯, 越々, and 応々” corresponds to the pronunciation equivalent to “おう” –　"oh" or "ou." They are pronounced respectively as "ying," "ming," "wei," "yue-yue" and "ying-ying" in Chinese. And all suggested words are pointless and utterly wrong. If you have just an elementary knowledge of Chinese language, you wouldn't make such a primitive and laughable mistake.

They are absolutely different beasts from “さあ,” “まあ” and “おう" either phonetically or semantically. If you have any objections, please contend with me to make your case. I'm waiting for your rebuttal.

Both “応" and "鳴" are  verbs each meaning "respond" and "sing, chirp, twitter." "唯”　is an adjective meaning "only, sole" in both Japanese and Chinese, ”越々” is an adverbial phrase meaning "the more ... the more," all irrelevant to “さあ,” “まあ,” and “おう" which are interjections.

The connection of "応々" in 去来's haiku with Chinese word is comically farfetched. There's no Chinese word spelt or vocalized like 応々, and if it should happen to be by chance, it must be read "ying-ying," not "ō, ō" as an answerer suggested.

I think @sqrtbottle is right. And only he was right.

If Japanese, “さあ” and “まあ” is a loan word from Chinese word or character that sounds “oo” as Samuel Martin says, it may be “哦” which is pronounced as "o" or "oh."

A Chinese language dictionary at hand, “多功用常用字典” - published by 新華出版社 in Beijing - defines “哦” as a "感嘆詞.表示懐疑或吃惊. 哦! 是这么回事. – [Exclamation] indicates a suspicion or surprise. Example. Oh, my God! What is this all about! "

However, I’m not sure whether “さあ” and “まあ” are really a loanword  from Chinese language.